# How do I NuGet Ninject.Web.Common?

Tags: nuget

All the examples seem to want the Ninject.Web.Common file reference.  I can NuGet Ninect and Ninject.Web.Mvc but I can't seem to get the .Common assembly.  It never comes up in the search results (I only have the default package source installed).  Is there some other package source I can try so I can get this reference and build the sample applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be installed from the official feed in the NuGet console with this command:

```
Install-Package Ninject.Web.Common -Pre
```

Ninject.Web.Common is currently in a prerelease state, it won't be listed in NuGet by default. (NuGet 1.7 will have an option to show the prerelease packages in the UI)

Package page in the official gallery :
http://nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.Common